# MySql select all records from the table with month and year in the range from that month and year to all the past

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I have a table with two fields "month" and "year" how can I make a query that, passing a month and a year, select everything from that month and year back.
For example, if the month and year in the query are 9 for the month and 2020 for the year, if I have records in the table that are from the same month and year or two previous months or one year or more in the past, do they all go out?

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option uses arithmetics:

```
select *
from mytable
where year * 100 + month <= date_format(current_date, '%Y%m')
```

Or:

```
where year * 100 + month <= year(current_date) * 100 + month(current_date)
```

Comment: year and month in the condition where are meant as values ​​passed to the query, so as in the example 2020 and 9?

Comment: @Robert: ok, so just replace `year(current_date)` with `2020` and `month(current_date)` with `9`. So: `where year * 100 + month <= :p_year * 100 + :p_month`, where `:p_year` and `:p_month` are the parameters to the query.

Comment: WHERE myTable.pay = 0

AND myTable.year * 100 + myTable.month <= 2020 * 100 + 9, I tried on PMA but it doesn't give any results

Comment: Sorry, it works, could you explain to me how this logic works please

Comment: Ok, I think I understand, you practically transform the date composed of month and year into a number, in the case of the example it would become 202009, doing the same process on the other dates so let's compare numbers and not real dates, this means that there is no native way to achieve the same result

Comment: @Robert: yes, you got it.